# How to make a variable declared in constructor visible in the main file

Tags: c

I have two c files :

1. `myconstructor.c` in which there is an implementation of `__attribute__ ((constructor))` so that it can execute before `main`
   : in this file I have declared a variable `a`.
2. `main.c` in which I try to access variable `a` : but I get `‘a’ undeclared (first use in this function)`

I have created a shared library in which I have included my constructor using `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
void myconstructor(){
    int a=5;
    printf("Hello from the constructor\n");
```

---

```
 int main(){
    printf("try to print a from  the main : %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are missing `extern int a;` in the main.c file?

Comment: It should be `int main(void)` and `void myconstructor(void)`

Comment: Relevant:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files?rq=1  Others here might even consider your question a duplicate of that one.

Comment: You probably want a separate header file that defines `extern int a;` that both your source files include.

Comment: @AndrewHenle and P.W These questions do not handle variables defined within functions.

Comment: I have tried using header file and extern but still the same problem,

Comment: @YoYoYonnY You mean declarations, not definitions. But this will also not work for variables defined locally.

Comment: @N.Omar That's because your `a` variable is a local variable, and doesn't exist outside of the function - and even then, it only exists when the function is running.

Comment: @Gerhardh *These questions do not handle variables defined within functions.*  Because there is no way to make a local variable visible.

Comment: My goal is to make the variable visible in main and declared in __attribute__constr.
So If I must use header file I did : extern int a;
And I have include the header file in both constructor and main but when I change the variable in constructor it does not appear in the main !!!!

Comment: If so how can do that ? is there any way ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't access local nonstatic variables of a function from another function. Especially not directly and especially if the function whose variables you want to access is finished.

Use a global. (Note that if you want to override a global defined in the main executable, you'll need to compile with `-rdynamic`).

Executable example:

```
#!/bin/sh -eu
cat > lib.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 5;
__attribute__ ((constructor))
static void myconstructor(void)
{
    a = 53; //pointless
    //^if the init value is known, you can simply use 
    //static initialization, omitting the constructor

    printf("Hello from the constructor\n");
}
EOF

cat > main.c <<'EOF'
#include <stdio.h>
#if EXTERN
extern int a;
#else
int a = 0;
#endif

int main(void)
{
    printf("try to print a from  the main : %d\n",a);
    return 0;
}
EOF
gcc lib.c -fpic -shared -o liblib.so
gcc -rdynamic  main.c -o inbuilt_overridable #-rdynamic makes the global overridable
gcc -L$PWD -DEXTERN main.c -llib -o nonabsolute_dynamic_lib
gcc -DEXTERN main.c $PWD/liblib.so  -o absolute_dynamic_lib

set -x
echo INBUILT
./inbuilt_overridable
echo ===

echo NON-ABSOLUTE DYNAMIC LIB
#if the lib isn't in standard system locations, you need the LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$PWD ./nonabsolute_dynamic_lib
echo ===

echo ABSOLUTE LIB
#I think Cygwin doesn't support this, but Linux definitely does
./absolute_dynamic_lib
echo ===

echo INBUILT OVERRIDDEN
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/liblib.so ./inbuilt_overridable
echo ===
```

Comment: @CacahueteFrito OK

Comment: target.c is main.c .
to compile :
gcc -g target.c -o target
gcc -g -c -Werror -fPIC myconstructor.c
gcc -shared -o ourlibrary.so myconstructor.o 
LD_PRELOAD=$PWD/ourlibrary.so ./target

----
I did really what is suggested but I get this error :


undefined reference to `a'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @N.Omar If you don't define a global `a` in the main executable, you'll need to link (at compile time, which isn't really linking, just a check that the lib provides the missing symbols) with `ourlibrary.so` (and then you don't need `LD_PRELOAD`). If you don't want to link with `ourlibrary.so` then your main executable or one of its linked libraries needs to provide a `a` symbol. If the `a` symbol isn't provided by a dynamic library, you'll need to compile with `-rdynamic` for it to be interposable. Example shown in my answer.

Comment: Yes I want to find out if I can do that without defining the variable in the main.c, you suggest by linking at compile time is that right ! 
So If i have understand I will not use LD_PRELOAD and I have just to compile my main.c with something like this : gcc -L/home/username/mylib -Wall -o test main.c -l(mylib) ?

Comment: @N.Omar Yes. I have now included that case in the executable example in my answer. Hope it's a little clearer now. (Dynamic linking is quite complex. Can't hope to cover all the edge cases in a SO answer.)